# Inserting data into the table

Tags: php, mysql, post, insert

I have three tables:actors, movies and roles. Table roles solves the problem of many-to-many relationship. Right now I am making a page to add a move to a database and assign an actor.

The form adds the movie to the table movies but it doesn't add a record to the table role. 
Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table class="addactor">
<tr>
<td class="right">Movie code:</td> <td><input type="text" class="textfield" name="moviecode" value="" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="right">Title:</td><td><input type="text" class="textfield" name="title" value="" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="right">Date:</td><td><input type="text" class="textfield" name="dateofissue" value="" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="right">Description:</td><td><input type="text" class="textfield" name="desc" value="" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="right">Link to the image:</td><td><input type="text" class="image" name="image1" value="" required></td>
</tr>


</table>
<?php
$sqlquery="SELECT artistId, firstname, lastname from $artists order by 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlquery);
if($result)
    {
        echo "<table class=\"addactor\">";
        echo "<tr>
    <td id=\"text\" colspan=\"2\"><h3>Assign an actor to the movie</h3></td>
    </tr>";
        while  ($sqlRow=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
            {


                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo"<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"".$sqlRow['artistId']."\" value=\"".$sqlRow['artistId']."\"/> ".$sqlRow['firstname']." ".$sqlRow['lastname']."</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"role\"></td>";
                echo "</tr>";



            }

        echo"<tr><td align=\"right\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Add\"></td><td><input type=\"reset\" name=\"reset\" id=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\"></td></tr></table>;";

    }
print '</table>';






if ($_POST)
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
            {
                $sqlqr="INSERT INTO $roll (artistId, movieCode, roleDescription) VALUES ('".$sqlRow['artistId']."', '".$_POST['moviecode']."', '".$_POST['role']."')";
            }
        $query = "INSERT INTO $movies(movieCode, title, dateOfIssue, description, image) VALUES ('".$_POST['moviecode']."', '".$_POST['title']."', '".$_POST['dateofissue']."', '".$_POST['desc']."', '".$_POST['image1']."')";


        if (!mysqli_query($connect,$query)||!mysqli_query($connect, $sqlqr))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
            }
        else
            {
                echo "<h4>1 record added</h4>";
            }



        print '</form>';
    }
    ?>
```

I would be really grateful if you could solve this problem!

Comment: You are forced to use this "style" or you can use a more elegant way? With "elegant way" i mean: 1 page where is the table to display, X php pages to manage actions to the database and use Ajax to send requests to the X php pages. Anyway in your query you used `$movies` and `$roll` if it's tables name use `movie` and `roll` without $ symbol.

Comment: Should it be `$role` instead of `$roll` in the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: where you have declared `$roll`,`$movies` ?

Comment: Your `foreach` loop is overwriting the `$sqlqr` variable each time, so at the end it just has the last query.

Comment: Why do you even need that loop? You never do anything with `$key` or `$value`.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, yes, everywhere role. I don't know much of php, so I tried to use $key and $value, because I saw it somewhere on the forum :) If I just put the query without the loop, will I get all the checked values?Because I can choose multiple actors, I don't know what kind of loop to use.

Comment: You should use array-style names for repeated inputs. Then `$_POST['fieldname']` will be an array that you can loop over.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm losing patience with people who just put code because they "saw it somewhere on the forum", and have no idea what it actually does. You can't program by cutting and pasting, you have to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Barmar before understanding I should try, right?And this forum is also for helping other people with different issues, so I don't really see the point for losing patience.

Comment: Problem is I can't figure out what you're trying to do if your code is full of meaningless statements.

Answer (score 1):

Replace $roll to role and $movies to movies and try this

```
INSERT INTO roll (artistId, movieCode, roleDescription) VALUES ('".$sqlRow['artistId']."', '".$_POST['moviecode']."', '".$_POST['role']."')";
$query = "INSERT INTO movies(movieCode, title, dateOfIssue, description, image) VALUES ('".$_POST['moviecode']."', '".$_POST['title']."', '".$_POST['dateofissue']."', '".$_POST['desc']."', '".$_POST['image1']."')";
```

Comment: Really i am the only one who sees this query really dangerous?